# how to get id value of the item (within item)?

Tags: extjs3

I need to get value for id, do this:

```
Application.Exaple = Ext.extend(Ext.form.FormPanel, {
record_id : 0,
initComponent : function() {
Ext.apply(this, {

                items: [
                {
                    name       : 'id',
                    id         : 'id',
                    fieldLabel : 'ID',
                    readOnly   : true,
                    hidden     : true,
                    listeners  : {
                        'render' : function() {
                            this.record_id = this.value;
                        }
                    }
                },
                {
                    name    : 'pum',
                    id      : 'pum',
                    handler : function() {
                        alert(this.record_id); // not work
                }
```

but does not work. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This looks like scope error.

you are trying to refer to the record while your current 'this' is the button.

You can do one of 2 things:

1) pass a scope to the handler like this:

```
{
  name    : 'pum',
  id      : 'pum',
  scope: YOUR OBJECT HERE,
  handler : function() {
     alert(this.record_id); // not work
}
```

2) register the click event of the button from outside like this:

after you call the base form super class on your init method...

```
{
...
this.numBtn = this.items.itemAt(1);
this.numBtn.on('click',function(){YOUR LOGIC HERE},YOUR SCOPE HERE);
}
```

Hope this helps...